# Touch move gesture logic...how to determine direction of movement in 2d?

Tags: android, algorithm, graphics, geometry

How can i determine the direction of gesture ? The use case is shown in the image link. what is the right logic for detecting in which direction the person is trying to move the ball in the circular path ? I have called the direction method in move gesture...Can someone help me fine tune this ... ?

http://www.shrenikvikam.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/214e422a43E11S3.png-150x134.png

```
     private String getDirection(float firstTouchX, float finalTouchX){
        if((firstTouchX - finalTouchX)>0)
            return "Left";
        else
            return "Right";
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {
            // MotionEvent class constant signifying a finger-down event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.d("ACTION DOWN","Value ->");
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();
                initialTouchX = x;
                initialTouchY = y;
                break;

            }
            // MotionEvent class constant signifying a finger-drag event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();
                final String direction = getDirection(initialTouchX,x);
                Log.d("ACTION MOVE","diff in initial and cur value of x  ->" + direction + (initialTouchX - x) + initialTouchX + "y->" + initialTouchY);

                break;

            }
            // MotionEvent class constant signifying a finger-up event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                Log.d("ACTION UP","Value ->");

                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I can't think of a proper way for tracking circular path right now but am wondering would it be more usable if you tracked up/down + left/right movement instead to adjust your spinner accordingly higher/lower values. For circular path, I'm guessing, you should calculate center point of this spinner and once user moves pointer you can calculate angle between movement points. And use this information to adjust this spinner more precisely.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the slope of the line formed by the two touch points should be equal to the tangent of the circle at that point. This link has most of the math to pursue such a [solution](http://www.analyzemath.com/CircleEq/Tutorials3.html)

I have used the difference between angles to the center point of the circle with good success. That may be the way to go as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to determine which way to move the ball around the ciricle, it doesn't make sense for `getDirection` to return `"Left"` and `"Right"`, it should be working with `"Clockwise"` and `"Counterclockwise"`. Consider, for example, when the ball is at the 20 marker in your image: At this point every point on the circle is `"Right"` of where you are now...

In order to determine if the ball is moving clockwise or counterclockwise you need to consider both the `x` and `y` co-ordinates of the touch points, the `x` co-ordinate alone is not sufficient. You also need to know where the centre of the circle is. I would suggest in order to determine the direction of movement, you calculate the angle between the touch points and the centre of the circle.

Comment: hmmm... let me try that out..btw..if you have some samples with similar integration as shown in the image link, do share it with me, actually struggling to get this done..

Answer (score 0):

```
                prevTouchX = event.getHistoricalX(event.getHistorySize()-1);
                currentTouchX = event.getX();
                if(currentTouchX<prevTouchX){
                    Log.d("LEFT",event.getX()+" and "+event.getY());
                }
                if(currentTouchX>prevTouchX){
                    Log.d("RIGHT",event.getX()+" and "+event.getY());
                }
```

Similarly for UP/DOWN

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for rotating a view. It works very well. Have a look at this;

```
switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                firstX = event.getX();
                firstY = event.getY();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int dx =(int) (event.getX() - firstX);
                int dy =(int) (event.getY() - firstY);

                Log.d("Distance Rotate Touch",Integer.toString((int) (firstX-dx)));

                if (signView.getRotation()<180){
                    if (firstX - dx > 15 && firstY - dy > 15 ){
                        View.setRotation(signView.getRotation()-5);
                    }else if(firstX - dx < -15 && firstY - dy < 15  ){
                        View.setRotation(signView.getRotation()+5);
                    }
                }else {
                    if (firstX - dx > 10 && firstY - dy < -10 ){
                        View.setRotation(signView.getRotation()+5);
                    }else if(firstX-dx < -10 && firstY - dy < -15 ){
                        View.setRotation(signView.getRotation()-5);
                    }
                }
                break;

            default: return true;
        }
```